# Repeated citations of type `comdoc' in OSCOLA

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, oscola

I am using [oscola-biblatex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/oscola) for my thesis. OSCOLA allows for repeated citations in a short format with a cross-reference to the full citation. This is typically handled really well by [oscola-biblatex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/oscola). However, it does not seem to work for entries of the sub-type `comdoc`. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[style=oscola,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
    @report{com13,
    title = {Action Plan on consumer access to justice
        and the settlement of disputes in the internal
        market},
    type = {Communication},
    number = {COM (96) 13 final},
    institution = {Commission},
    entrysubtype = {comdoc}
    }

    @report{autumnperf,
    title = {2008 Autumn Performance Report},
    institution = {Department for Children, Schools
        and Families},
    series = {Cm},
    number = {7507},
    date = {2008},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
Here is some text with a first reference to the `comdoc' 
document.\footcite{com13}
And here a reference to a general report.\footcite{autumnperf}
The repeated citation to the `comdoc' document will output the full 
citation.\footcite{com13}
Whereas the repeated citation to anything else works as 
expected.\footcite{autumnperf}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

When compiled, this produces:
[image: Footnote citations]

The repeated citation for the general report works as expected (with a cross-reference to fn. 2). The repeated citation for the `comdoc` entrysubtype produces the full citation again. According to the [oscola-biblatex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/oscola) manual, [p. 72](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex-contrib/oscola/oscola.pdf):

> Subsequent references will use simply the com number, as
>   oscola requires.

How can I troubleshoot this so repeated citations only output the `number` field if the `entrysubtype` is `comdoc`? Is it a problem with [oscola](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/oscola)'s driver, and if so, could I patch it through [xpatch](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xpatch)?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In case you were thinking about it, better don't update `biblatex` and Biber until https://github.com/PaulStanley/oscola-biblatex/pull/8 is resolved.

Comment: @moewe thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this appears to go explicitly against documented behaviour (and apparently against behaviour required by OSCOLA style) I *strongly* urge you to open an issue at https://github.com/PaulStanley/oscola-biblatex/issues.

Currently, `oscola.cbx` contains

```
\renewbibmacro*{footcite:note}{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifentrytype{legislation}}
              or ( test {\ifentrytype{legal}} 
                   and ( not test {\iffieldequals{entrysubtype}{\treatysubtype}} ))}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:short}}%
    {\ifboolexpr{ test {\ifentrytype{commentary}} 
                   or  ( test {\ifentrytype{legal}} and not test {\iffieldequals{entrysubtype}{\treatysubtype}}) }%
      {\usebibmacro{footcite:full}}%
      {\ifboolexpr{ ( test {\ifentrytype{jurisdiction}} 
                      and 
                    ( not test {\iffieldundef{userc}} 
                      and not test {\iffieldundef{postnote}} )) 
                    or (test {\ifentrytype{legal}} 
                        and test {\iffieldequalstr{type}{parliamentary}} )}
         {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}%
     {\ifboolexpr{ ( test {\ifentrytype{report}} and test {\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{comdoc}} )}
            {\usebibmacro{cite:refonlyfull}} % FIX THIS: will need a separate macro
            {\usebibmacro{footcite:note:old}}}}}}%
```

And the `FIX THIS` comment is exactly at the line that needs to be fixed here.

If I understand correctly the following small redefinition might do what you want

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[style=oscola,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{footcite:note}{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifentrytype{legislation}}
              or ( test {\ifentrytype{legal}} 
                   and ( not test {\iffieldequals{entrysubtype}{\treatysubtype}} ))}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:short}}%
    {\ifboolexpr{ test {\ifentrytype{commentary}} 
                   or  ( test {\ifentrytype{legal}} and not test {\iffieldequals{entrysubtype}{\treatysubtype}}) }%
      {\usebibmacro{footcite:full}}%
      {\ifboolexpr{ ( test {\ifentrytype{jurisdiction}} 
                      and 
                    ( not test {\iffieldundef{userc}} 
                      and not test {\iffieldundef{postnote}} )) 
                    or (test {\ifentrytype{legal}} 
                        and test {\iffieldequalstr{type}{parliamentary}} )}
         {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}%
         {\ifboolexpr{ ( test {\ifentrytype{report}} and test {\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{comdoc}} )}
            {\usebibmacro{cite:comdoc}}
            {\usebibmacro{footcite:note:old}}}}}}%

\makeatletter
\newbibmacro{cite:comdoc}{%
  \printfield{number}%
  \iffootnote
    {\setunit*{\addspace}
     \bbx@unsetpostnotedelim
     \printtext[parens]{%
       \midsentence
       \bibstring{seenote}\addnbspace
       \ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}%
       \iftoggle{cbx:pageref}%
         {\ifsamepage{\the\value{instcount}}%
                     {\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}%
            {}%
            {\addcomma\space\bibstring{page}\addnbspace%
             \pageref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}}
         {}}}
    {}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@report{com13,
  title        = {Action Plan on consumer access to justice
                  and the settlement of disputes in the internal
                  market},
  type         = {Communication},
  number       = {COM (96) 13 final},
  institution  = {Commission},
  entrysubtype = {comdoc},
}
@report{autumnperf,
  title       = {2008 Autumn Performance Report},
  institution = {Department for Children, Schools
                 and Families},
  series      = {Cm},
  number      = {7507},
  date        = {2008},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Here is some text with a first reference to the `comdoc'
document.\footcite[12]{com13}
And here a reference to a general report.\footcite[13]{autumnperf}
The repeated citation to the `comdoc' document will output the full
citation.\footcite[14]{com13}
Whereas the repeated citation to anything else works as
expected.\footcite[15]{autumnperf}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

We just replace the generic macro `cite:refonlyfull` by a specialised `cite:comdoc` that just prints the number.

[image: 1 Commission, “Action Plan on consumer access to justice and the settlement of disputes in the internal market” (Communication) COM (96) 13 final.//2 Department for Children, Schools and Families, 2008 Autumn Performance Report (Cm 7507, 2008)//3 COM (96) 13 final//4 2008 Autumn Performance Report (n 2).]

Comment: Many thanks, this works brilliantly. I've adjusted your `cite:comdoc` bib macro to satisfy OSCOLA's requirement that short citations point to the full citation. I'm posting it to your answer as a proposed edit.

Comment: Also [new issue](https://github.com/PaulStanley/oscola-biblatex/issues/9) now submitted along with your proposed fix at oscola's github page.

Comment: @Nikko I slightly changed the code you added about the footnote references to play nice with the postnote delimiter. (Of course I don't know what OSCOLA wants, so I'm just guessing from other examples in the style.)